# Como posso buscar um arquivo html do meu servidor e incorporar em uma pagina cliente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Desenvolvi um chat, para implementar é preciso adicionar na pagina do cliente um .js(Assim o cliente não tem o trabalho de criar a marcação no seu site, é só importar o js e pronto, como um plugin jquery qualquer), ele funciona basicamente assim, existe uma pagina html onde ele busca a marcação(html) e joga dentro do body da pagina cliente, fiz da seguinte forma:

Isso é um exemplo(O código original é maior, mas este trecho resume o problema)

```
var ffchat = ffchat || (function () {
    return {
        addChat: function (Args) {
            $(function () {
                $.get('http://meuhost.com/chat/partial_chat.html', function (data) {
                    var html = $(data);
                    $("body").append(html);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}());
```

Funcionou perfeitamente nos meus testes locais(Mesmo host), o problema é que o navegador bloqueia esta requisição quando é para outro host, ele impede que eu pegue o html no meu servidor.

Como posso buscar um arquivo html do meu servidor e incorporar em uma pagina cliente?

Lembrando que este arquivo tem css, js e html para personalizar o chat na pagina cliente, o chat esta em um iframe dentro deste arquivo.

Comment: Tentou liberar CORS no seu servidor ?

Comment: Mas esta liberação é feita na maquina cliente ou no meu servidor? Porque se for na maquina cliente não resolve meu problema.

Comment: A liberação é feita no seu servidor. No caso seu servidor deve dizer que outros sites podem enviar requisições para ele. Em qual linguagem seu servidor foi feito ?

Comment: criei um htacess e coloquei Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
, mas não adiantou.

Comment: Depois de colocar esta regra, não consigo nem acessar mais o js, fiz uma pesquisa rápida sobre cors, se você quiser postar alguma reposta utilizando o cors

Comment: Não tenho muita certeza se este é o problema. E a liberação de cors não é padronizada para os servidores, precisaria saber qual linguagem usou para  também fazer uma pesquisa e conseguir te responder melhor.

Comment: basicamente fiz um plugin jquery que importa um html, estou usando jquery, o chat é php, mas isso não importa já que ele esta dentro de um iframe.

Comment: tentou com $('body').load("minha_pagina.html"); ?

Comment: Sim, o efeito é o mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Eu passei por um problema bem parecido.
Na época eu fiz o seguinte.
Coloquei esse código dentro do meu apache2.conf (Embaixo da linha aonde vc declara o .htacess)

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header unset Etag
```

E depois disso eu dei um restart no apache2 e funcionou normalmente

Comment: Eu consigo fazer esta mesma configuração mas utilizando .htaccess? Porque há outros sistemas rodando neste servidor, sistemas maiores, por isso queria evitar de mexer nas configurações do servidor.